# upload to local WebDav - spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, inputstream, webdav

I have problem with upload file to local WebDav. So far i have:

```
public interface IStorageService {
    URI SaveFile(String filename, InputStream inputStream);
}
```

```
@Component
public class LocalStorageService implements IStorageService {
    @Value( "C:\temp" )
    private String filestorePath;
    
    public URI SaveFile(String filename, InputStream inputStream) {
        var rootLocation = Paths.get(filestorePath);
        var filePath = rootLocation.resolve(filename);
        try {
            Files.copy(inputStream, filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failure save file to " + filename + " in " + filestorePath + "." + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return filePath.toUri();
    }
}
```

and controller

```
    private final DocumentService documentService;

    public DocumentController(DocumentService documentService) {
        this.documentService = documentService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public DocumentModel handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {        
        return documentService.handleFileUpload(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream());
    }
```

And it is works correctly, the file is uploaded to C:/temp...
Now I would like to do the same but upload file to local WebDav. When i change in @Value "C:\temp to "http://localhost" (this is ma webdav location) i have:

```
invalidpathexception: illegal char <:> at index 4: http://localhost
```

or when I declare http//localhost without <:>

```
nosuchfileexception: http\localhost
```

How can I write my code to upload file directly to WebDav.
Parameters of SaveFile method cannot be changed, I need do it with Name as String and InputStream.
I tried with Sardine but to no avail. Could someone help me, give any tips or maybe suggestion of code ?

Greetings !

Comment: The `java.nio.Files` stuff isn't called `Files` without a reason. That only works for actual file resources not for arbitrary URLs. You will need a better WebDAV client to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path where your web app/ war/ servlet / controllers are deployed :

ServletContext context = getContext();
String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/test/foo.txt");

For a Spring project, in controller

```
'@Autowired
'ServletContext context;
```

And in controller method :

```
'String uploadPath = context.getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
```

And the real file name, but what if a user uploads same file twice or 2 users upload file with same name?

Better to put in sub directory with user id/ user name and maybe date time or some other identifier like TXN id + some fixed text like

```
' String fileName = context.getRealPath("") + File.separator + userId + readlName + "xyz."
```

- extnFromMimeType;

And store the path in data base for this transaction/ user as per your busibess use case.

if mime type is image/PMG then extnFromMimeType will be "png"; if jpeg or jpg then "jpg"

See

- [File path to resource in our war/WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder)
- [how to get getServletContext() in spring mvc Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923907/how-to-get-getservletcontext-in-spring-mvc-controller)
- [In Spring MVC, how can I set the mime type header when using @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471584/in-spring-mvc-how-can-i-set-the-mime-type-header-when-using-responsebody)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

If can be many images per user/ transaction can also use createTemp File to get a unique file name
using a UUID also possible ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293712/1643558 or a large random number